Why does Peter Tork say, "Where there is choice, there is misery"?
In Head (1968), why does Peter Tork say, "Where there is choice, there is misery"? In this scene, the Yogi says it, but he repeats it in the next scene.



Plus, Pete wrote the movie (with Nicholson).
It must have to do with, "Where there is clarity, there is no choice."


Where there is clarity, there is no choice. And where there is choice, there is misery. But then, why should I speak, since I know nothing?

The movie "Head" is about the nature of free will. The quote is from Jiddu Krishnamurti, an Indian philosopher. For the exact meaning of the idea, and a deeper understanding of it, it's probably better to discuss that on some psychology/philosophy related site. But it boils down to "where there is will there is choice, but choice can be an illusion".




Tork must have watched this before writing Head. Ty.
